# Proving that a given gate is universal

Tags: boolean-algebra

The question is:

Given gate called NEW has 4 inputs and 1 output

```
NEW(w,x,y,z)=zy(w+z)
```

Is NEW is Universal logic gate?

I found that the gate is not universal because I can't create `NOT` gate with it. 
How should I prove it?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show that $NEW(1,1,1,1)=1$, and then use induction to show that no matter $NEW$ gates you string together, you'll always end up with $1$ on the output if all inputs are $1$

Comment: Thanks! is it possible to prove also by truth table?

Comment: You need a meta-logical argument .. so you could reason *about* truth-tables, but you can't prove this using a single truth-table.